# CakePHP: create bar chart

Tags: php, cakephp, charts, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP (v3.0) and I want to create a bar chart.
I have tried to use "libchart" and "pchart" libraries but always I get problems (I think that namespaces is one of them..) to import and use these libraries on my controller class...

What's the simplest way to create a bar chart on CakePHP 3 ?

Comment: You can place the chart libraries in vendor folder and include them using PHP `include` function. To call their class just use a backslash befor them like `$chart = new \VerticalBarChart(500, 250);`

Comment: To Whomsoever placed this on hold: The question have enough information to be answered. The PO gave the hint of `namespaces`. The one who has worked on cakephp 3 can understand this. Please unhold the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the chart libraries in `vendor` folder and include them using PHP's `include` function.

To call their class just use a backslash before them to make them a **Fully qualified name** like 
`$chart = new \VerticalBarChart(500, 250);`

Now you can use `$chart` without any issues.

**References:**

[PHP Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)